# Pandas OHLCV to JSON format

Tags: python, json, pandas, resampling

I have real time data that I resample with pandas in order to get OHLCV data:

```
ohlcv = df.resample(_period).agg({'bid': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
            volume         bid
            volume        open        high      low       close
timestamp
2016-09-01   300.0   77.644997   78.320331   77.638   78.320331
```

and the JSON output using `ohlcv.to_json(orient='index')` is:

```
{"1472688000000":{"["volume","volume"]":300.0,"["bid","open"]":77.644997,"["bid","high"]":78.320331,"["bid","low"]":77.638,"["bid","close"]":78.320331}}
```

How can I convert the dataframe in the following JSON:

```
{
   "timestamp":1472688000000,
   "open":77.644997,
   "high":78.320331,
   "close":78.320331,
   "low":77.638,
   "volume":300
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) for convert `MultiIndex` in columns to flatten columns:

```
ohlcv = df.resample(_period).agg({'bid': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
ohlcv.columns = ohlcv.columns.droplevel(0)

ohlcv.to_json(orient='index')
```